# Необходимо показать сайт только в iframe другого сайта

Tags: iframe

Необходим рендер одного сайта в айфрейме другого, и чтобы при попытке зайти напрямую в браузере на сайт из iframe, редиректило на сайт с iframe или например выкидывало ошибку 403.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window == window.top)
  window.location = "http://...";
```

Comment: Если у клиента отключен js в браузере? Надо именно, чтобы в любом случае работало в iframe и иначе не показывалось.

Comment: @JohnRoget Тогда Вам не повезло.